# javascript clock with timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

would like to show time on my site with seconds counting, like [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock). I know there is a lot of similar questions, but I was not able to find out a solution that would work for me. Problem is, all those javascript clock that handle timezone are done by offset.

I am however using django timezones: "UTC", "Asia/Harbin", ...
Javascript on default creates new date from local time, but I allow user to change his/hers timezone. How do I pass this changed timezone to javascript?
I tried moment-timezone, but it somehow ignores .tz().

```
<script>
function startTime() {
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = moment().tz("{{ TIME_ZONE }}").format('HH:mm:ss');
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}
</script>
```

This way time is running, but changing timezone has no impact on time. How do I do this properly?

Comment: Your code works just fine.  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t59q4b89/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the problem is that you are loading moment-timezone without any data.  Try using one of the prepackaged bundles on the moment-timezone site, such as moment-timezone-2010-2020.js, or moment-timezone-all-years.js.

See the [moment-timezone docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. I am sorry I did not read docs more carefully.

Comment: No problem.  Easy mistake to make.  Note that as of moment-timezone 0.2.0 or greater, it will warn you if you have no data loaded or the time zone specified cannot be found in the data you have.